# Image appear then disapper in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

In my website, i change the div which contains the images using jQuery:

```
 <div class='bar1' >
    <div class='blocks'> <a href='#' >Home</a></div>
    <div class='blocks'> <a href='#'>About</a></div>
    <div class='blocks'><a href='#'>Zones</a></div>
    <div class='blocks'><a href='#'>Players</a></div>
 </div>
<div class='block-top-container'>
   <div class='scroll-block'>
      <img src='ban1/1.jpg' alt ='' />
   </div>
   <div class='scroll-block'>
     <img src='ban1/2.jpg' alt ='' />
   </div>
   <div class='scroll-block'>
      <img src='ban1/10.jpg' alt ='' />
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery code to move left the images on link clicked

```
$(window).load(function() {

    $(".bar1  a").click(function(e){

    var $this = $(this);
    var index = $this.parent().index();
    var left = (index * $(" .scroll-block ").width());

    $(" .block-top-container ").animate({ marginLeft: -(left) }, 500);


    });

 });
```

The error happens in Chrome (Version 23). The image loads but after the page load is completed the image disappears and we see a broken image icon.

I checked the Network tab in Chrome developer tools there when the page loads the image appears but after the page load completes the image disappears, in network tab the Image Get Failed error is displayed.

[image: Image of the error]

Comment: `+1` for opening the developer tools. Almost *nobody* who asks questions here does that. Did you try in any other browsers?

Comment: Yes it works in Firefox and IE 9, When i searched google i say a similar problem/Bug but that was in Chrome 19 or something and it should have been resolved by now i taught

Comment: Does it give you a status code for the error?